# Best place to add Google plugin?

Tags: 7

I need to add smart Google translate plugin from [Here](https://translate.google.com/manager/website/) , where is the best place in code, so I could add it to header, somewhere here?

[image]

It is a header, but should I add it to `html.tpl.php` or somewhere else?

Comment: I will suggest you to add place the code inside a block & place block to header section. If you strictly wanted to add this code in template file then place it in header of html.tpl.php.

Comment: @Rupesh thank you, I will try do it with blocks as you suggested.